# Android: Bluetooth Chat. connect to mHandler in MainActivity from another Class

Tags: android, bluetooth, handler

I made the android Bluetooth-Chat tutorial. Instead of using the OnClickListeners in the main acitivity, I want to use the OnClickListeners in an other class (MyCursorAdapter.class).

I think its a very simple java problem. But I don't know  how to implement this (how can I use mHandler from the other activity in my class).

Can anybody helpe me?

Cheers Felix

**Source in the MainActivity.class (is working well)**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private BluetoothService mChatService = null;

...
    private void setupChat() { 
    mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            byte[] out = {32};  
            mChatService.write(out);
            mChatService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler);
        }
   });
 }
```

**Source In MyCursorAdapter.class (here I want to implement the same function)**

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener {
...

        private class OffItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int position;

        public OffItemClickListener(int position) {
            super();
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
               // byte[] out = {32};
               // MainAcitivity.talkChat(out);  
               // error: "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"


               // Here i want to the the same like in the MainActivity class. 
               // But how can I connect to the mHandler?         
        }
        }
  }
```

**Comment:**

**Instance of MyCursorAdapter in MainActivity**

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);


    adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, notesCursor);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Comment comment:**

**Or how can I call this MainActivity method from MyCursorAdapter?:**

```
public void talkChat(byte[] out) { 
   mChatService.write(out); 
   mChatService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler); 
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an instance of mhandler in your MyCursorAdapter class

```
     public class MyCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter implements  
    OnClickListener {

    private Handler mHandler;

    public void setMHandler(Handler mHandler){
        this.mHandler = mHandler;

    private class OffItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private int position;

    public OffItemClickListener(int position) {
        super();
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
           // byte[] out = {32};
           // MainAcitivity.talkChat(out);  
           // error: "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

             Use your mhandler...
           // Here i want to the the same like in the MainActivity class. 
           // But how can I connect to the mHandler?         
    }
    }
    }
```

And Reference it from your MainActivity

```
private void fillData() {
  Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
 startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, notesCursor);
adapter.setMHandler(mHandler); //Reference  
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

}

Comment: No MyCursorAdapter does extand ResourceCursorAdapter. I added it to my post. At first I tried to create a new method to the main acitity `public void talkChat(byte[] out) { mChatService.write(out);
            mChatService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler); }`. But when I call it from MyCursorAdapter I reciefed the message "can not make a static reference to the non-static method".

Comment: Do you have an instance of MyCursorAdapter in MainActivity Class?

Comment: Yes I have a instance of MyCursorAdapter in the Main Acitivity class (See the comment in my post). The second comment was the first thing I tried. But I can't call it from the MyCursorAdapter.java with MyAcitivity.talkChat(...)